# Is it a real-time operation when reading the files on the disk on Vxworks?

Tags: rtos, vxworks

In no doubt that we can read files on the disk on Vxworks.

The question is whether it's a real-time API or not.

If the answer is not, one more question arises.

Is it possible to implement a real-time API to read the files on the disk?

Comment: What do you mean by real-time? It does not make much sense for an API to be real-time or not. It is the OS that is real-time. What is the behaviour you expect from said API?

Comment: @Emut Vxworks is real-time OS. The definition of real-time could be easily found by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more on the context for the question and what you intend to address?
If you are asking if a read operation on a disk can be blocked, then the answer would be yes but it would depend on how the I/O layer is implemented for the driver being used.
In case you do not want to have a blocking operation on a read, you still be able to use select() to detect if an read operation can be performed on the device.
In addition you might use ioctl() commands to get information on the device or the file.

Answer (score 0):

"real-time" OS means you have defined time-slices and monitoring of time effort, that's it.